# Moving background effect above cell.

Tags: css

A little while back with some great help from SO I was able to create an effect where a mouse over causes the background to do an animated underline effect:

```
.box{
    height:30px;
    background-color : white;
}
.simulate_border {
    position : relative;
    height : 35px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, grey 50%);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position:right bottom;
    transition:all 500ms ease;
}

.simulate_border:hover{
        background-position:left bottom; 
 }
```

Seen in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/9a4MW/

Now I wanted to see if I could do the same but above the content rather than below. But after much fiddling can't get the effect to be above rather than below?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just position your `.box` differently: [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bdqrc6pu/).

```
.box {
    height:30px;
    background-color : white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure I fully understand this type of positioning yet!

Comment: It relies on `.simulate_border` having `position: relative`. Relative positioning provides a new positioning context, so to say.

Comment: A follow on question, this is my actual implementation using table based divs. I can get it to appear above, but it causes a big space between the line and the content. Any ideas?  http://jsfiddle.net/0203t4hq/1/

Comment: Your `.headerCell` needs `position: relative`, as shown before above, and your `.innerHeaderCell` needs `width: 100%`, as shown before above.